# HTML move span to the max side inside h3

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code:

HTML:

```
<h3 class="section_title">Lorem ipsum <span class="c">Text</span></h3>
```

CSS:

```
    .main_description  .section_cost .section_title {
    font-size:      18px;
    border-bottom:  1px solid #ffffff; 
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right:   60px;
}
```

I want to move the text inside the span to the max right side of the h3 underline even if i change the text inside the span to a longer or shorter one.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzf5S.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

```
 span{float: right}
```

Here is something about this [CSS Layout - float and clear](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Comment: Floating shouldn't be used for general positioning of elements. It's used to put an image next to text.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `right` attribute:

```
right: 0;
position: relative;
```

That sets the offset from the right hand side.

Edit:

I forgot about setting the position as well.

Comment: That does not help :(